# walking through a building created in google sketchup

Tags: linux, rendering, sketchup, panda3d

I am looking for a way to take a model of a building and allow people to walk through it like a video engine.

We are also looking to run this on a viz wall, which requires OpenGL on Linux and be open source. But Something running on windows or closed source on Linux would be better than nothing.

I have found Panda3D, but I am not sure that will perform well enough for such a large model, the .egg file was over 200MB and took over 8GB of RAM to convert to their binary format.

None of our prefessors know about this, and we are having trouble finding the tools we need.

Comment: So you want to create the model in SU, and then export it into another program?

Comment: We asked the Panda3D devs what they thought about what we were doing, and we were converting into an extremely inefficient format(virtual reality something). We used an addon(egg something?) to blender and everything worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Flux Player, i used this on a school project a while ago.

If i recall correctly i had to export the sketchup file with the extention that the program needs, but i don't remember at the moment which one was that.

http://www.redorbit.com/news/technology/854384/media_machines_releases_flux_studiotm_20_and_flux_playertm_20/
software belongs to "media machines"

this is basically a plugin that allows you to navigate the models on a web browser using your cursor or mouse.

I believe that there are other solutions out there that allow you to do exactly what you want.